# Search for Month and Day in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

New to elastic search, please help.
My date mapping is as below

```
{'mappings': {'properties':{
            'Reference': {'fields': {'keyword': {'ignore_above': 100,'type': 'keyword'}},'type': 'text'},
            'refdate':{'type': 'date','format':'yyyy-MM-dd'}}}
```

How to search for '*Month*' and '*day*' , example search for all 'Reference' where `refdate` is 02-21 (*22nd Feb, irrespective of year*)

Tried below query but getting an error

```
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "filter" : {
            "script" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['refdate'].date.getMonthValue() == 02 && doc['refdate'].date.getDayOfMonth() == 21",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> `RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')`

Answer (score 0):

below query is working

```
qry = {"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "filter" : {
            "script" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['refdate'].value.getMonthValue() == 02 && doc['refdate'].value.getDayOfMonth() == 21",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}

es.search(index='indexName', body=qry, size=100)
```

as mentioned in docs

> Fields of type long and date had `getDate()` and `getDates()` methods (for multi valued fields) to get an object with date specific helper methods for the current doc value. In 5.3.0, date fields were changed to expose this same date object directly when calling `doc["myfield"].value`, and **the getter methods for date objects were deprecated. These methods have now been removed**(from 7.0). Instead, use `.value` on date fields, or explicitly parse long fields into a date object using `Instance.ofEpochMillis(doc["myfield"].value)`.

refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-datetime.html#_datetime_pieces_examples) how to extract day,year,month etc.